# 18.04 with VirtualBox 6: Need Help installing alfa awus036ach USB attached WiFi

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, virtualbox

I am trying to install the USB-attached [alfa awus036ach](https://www.alfa.com.tw/products_detail/1.htm) WiFi adapter to look at my home network with Kali as a virtual machine.

Very new to Ubuntu, Linux, and command line. I installed Ubuntu 18.04, VirtualBox 6.0 in Ubuntu, and Kali Linux 19.04 inside VirtualBox.

[lsusb](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/lsusb.8.html) shows that the alfa is connected. I tried: https://tacticalware.com/install-alfa-awus036ach-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Here I had issues coping files to the correct folder. Did not work for me

Also tried, unsuccessfully, https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

I pretty sure am making errors and are unable/unfamiliar enough with Linux and command line to see my mistakes

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. Also if it is not too much the why.

```
lsusb -v

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  idProduct          0x8812 RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           53
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           5
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

Comment: Yes. 18.04 is main OS. I have installed driver on virtual kali

Comment: Would you please rerun `lsusb -v` and post the relevant bits about your Alfa device into the question by clicking [edit]? No need to reply with a Comment, I will see your revision; using Add Comment is kinda marginal for putting new data in, for everything you find should go in the Question through [edit]. Besides, there's no formatting to speak up in Comments; see editing tips at http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @NotYou10913 did you use DKMS or 'Make' to install RTL8812AU from aircrack-ng GitHub repo?

Comment: @notyou10913 I've posted an answer with detailed steps. Let us know whether the answer is working for you or not. Thanks.

Comment: @notyou10913 you said, `Had to, cd rtl8812au`. Yes that is because the `dkms-install.sh` script is inside the folder `rtl8812au` you would have downloaded using `git clone` command. Can you please run the commands in the sequence as I have detailed in my answer, and let us know if it works for you. With the `DKMS` method, you do not need to run `make` or `make install`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all Greatly Appreciated!!!

Comment: @notyou10913 I'm glad that it worked out well for you. Also it would be great, if you could edit your OP and remove `make, make install` and other parts that didn't work previously, so future visitors who come across this thread won't get confused. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install the latest drivers from this GitHub repo: `https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git`

As per the repo, this is how you can install the drivers using DKMS method:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms
git clone -b v5.6.4.2 https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Your USB WiFi adapter should be working now.